# Lognest date sequence / group sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, lead

```
create table test_d as
SELECT price, to_date(startdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') startdate
FROM (
 SELECT 632 as price,'2019-05-01' as startdate FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 649,'2019-05-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 632,'2019-05-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 607,'2019-05-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 598,'2019-05-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 624,'2019-05-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 641,'2019-05-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 598,'2019-05-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 556,'2019-05-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 480,'2019-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 510,'2019-05-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 541,'2019-05-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 634,'2019-05-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 634,'2019-05-14' FROM DUAL );
```

There is a table. 
i want to find longest consecutive date sequence starting from date with lowest price. 
so in this case

```
1   480 2019-05-10  1   2019-05-09  0
2   510 2019-05-11  2   2019-05-10  0
3   541 2019-05-12  3   2019-05-11  0
```

What i've already done:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       case
         when startdate = next_d + 1 then 1
         else 0
       end seq 
FROM   (SELECT t.*,
               NVL(LAG(startdate) over(order by rnk asc),startdate-1) next_d
        FROM   (select price,
                       startdate,
                       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY price ASC) AS RNK
                from   test_d) t) t1
```

which gives me:

```
1   480 2019-05-11  1   2019-05-10  1
2   510 2019-05-10  2   2019-05-11  0
3   541 2019-05-12  3   2019-05-10  0
4   556 2019-05-09  4   2019-05-12  0
5   598 2019-05-05  5   2019-05-09  0
6   598 2019-05-08  6   2019-05-05  0
7   607 2019-05-04  7   2019-05-08  0
8   624 2019-05-06  8   2019-05-04  0
9   632 2019-05-01  9   2019-05-06  0
10  632 2019-05-03  10  2019-05-01  0
11  634 2019-05-13  11  2019-05-03  0
12  634 2019-05-14  12  2019-05-13  1
13  641 2019-05-07  13  2019-05-14  0
14  649 2019-05-02  14  2019-05-07  0
```

How can i group sequence in SEQ column? Like the first row gets number 1, rows 2-11 gets number 2, 12 - 3, 13-14 - 0 etc.?
Or mayby anyone has idea for another approach? 
Thanks

Comment: Why do rows 2-11 get the number 2? They don't seem to be in date order to me

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below query output

```
select t.*, startdate - nvl(LAG(startdate) over(order by price,startdate asc),startdate) date_diff from test_d t
```

is column date_diff with the greater value the answer to what you are trying to achieve? i.e 634 13-MAY-19   10

Output

```
PRICE   STARTDATE   DATE_DIFF
480 10-MAY-19   0
510 11-MAY-19   1
541 12-MAY-19   1
556 09-MAY-19   -3
598 05-MAY-19   -4
598 08-MAY-19   3
607 04-MAY-19   -4
624 06-MAY-19   2
632 01-MAY-19   -5
632 03-MAY-19   2
634 13-MAY-19   10
634 14-MAY-19   1
641 07-MAY-19   -7
649 02-MAY-19   -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but this query shows all groups of data where price was growing:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=341aa3b33122e7d1ad9f3cc06e51c502)</sup>**

```
select min(startdate) mnd, max(startdate) mxd, count(1) cnt, 
       listagg(price, ' -> ') within group (order by startdate) prices
  from (
    select price, startdate, chg, sum(chg) over (order by startdate) grp
      from (
        select price, startdate, 
               case when lag(price) over (order by startdate) < price then 0 else 1 end chg 
          from test_d t))
  group by grp
```

So for your samples output is:

```
MND         MXD                CNT PRICES
----------- ----------- ---------- -----------------------------
2019-05-01  2019-05-02           2 632 -> 649
2019-05-03  2019-05-03           1 632
2019-05-04  2019-05-04           1 607
2019-05-05  2019-05-07           3 598 -> 624 -> 641
2019-05-08  2019-05-08           1 598
2019-05-09  2019-05-09           1 556
2019-05-10  2019-05-13           4 480 -> 510 -> 541 -> 634
2019-05-14  2019-05-14           1 634
8 rows selected
```

The longest period is between 10 and 13 May, four consecutive rows.